# Does this sequence converges?

Tags: real-analysis

Supposed you have the set 
$$
S = \left\lbrace \frac{3}{10}, \frac{33}{100}, \frac{333}{1000},\ldots\right\rbrace
$$

As we can see it is just starting off as 0.3 and adding a three each time 0.33 etc, but can we say it converges to a value? From what I know it does not converge and therefore, does not have a least upper bound in $\mathbb Q$, but can have a least upper bound such as in

$$
S \subseteq R
$$
$$
R = \left\lbrace \frac{n}{10^k} \;\Big|\; n \in \mathbb Z, k \geq 1 \right\rbrace
$$

Comment: it converges to $0.\dot{3}=\frac{1}{3}$, isn't it?

Comment: Prove it converges using the definition.

Comment: Probably you intend to ask whether the **sequence** $0.3, 0.33, 0.333, 0.3333,\dots$ converges.

Comment: Euler...Is_Alive what definition are you suggesting? Thank you everyone for the help. Since there is always a rational number between any two rational numbers there is no least upper bound for S in Q.

Comment: That reasoning is faulty, Rules. This sequence provides a nice counterexample, showing that *sometimes* least upper bounds *are* in $\Bbb Q$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given sequence may be written in this form:
$$u_n=\frac{1}{10^n}\sum_{k=1}^n3\times10^{k-1}$$
hence 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}u_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{3}{10^{n+1}}\times10\frac{10^{n}-1}{10-1}=\frac{1}{3}$$

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Sets do not converge, *sequences* converge.  The sequence
$$s_1 = 0.3$$
$$s_2 = 0.33$$
$$s_3 = 0.333$$
$$\vdots$$
does indeed converge.  To see this observe that $s_n = \frac{1}{3}(1 - 10^{-n})$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty}10^{-n} = 0$. Thus $\lim_{n \to \infty} s_n = \frac{1}{3}$, which is an element of $\mathbb Q$. And S is bounded: 
$$ S \subset \left[\frac{3}{10},\frac{1}{3}\right].$$